# NodeJS ImageMagick How to convert Image with Transparent background

Tags: node.js, image, imagemagick, node-imagemagick

I want to convert my png with white background to transparent background png.

Here is my code.

```js
im.convert(
        [source, '-flatten', '-transparent', path_to],
        function (err, stdout) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          resolve(stdout);
        },
      );
```

And im getting this error.

```
Error: Command failed: convert:  `./../uploads/resized_613c98fa-e56e-4a57-ba70-9b1178ad7179.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3319.
```

I'm not able to use 'transparent'. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make white transparent, you need:

```
... '-flatten', '-transparent', 'white' ...
```

If you need nearly whites to become transparent as well as pure whites, add some fuzz beforehand:

```
... '-flatten', '-fuzz', '20%' ...
```

Comment: Thanks mate. You are right. I have to act like cli command